# \b\*\b fails to find asterisk in example strings, .NET c# [fix added]

Tags: c#, .net, regex

WHAT is wrong with the following regular expression and HOW does one fix it?:

```
    \b\*\b
```

The above pattern should be interpreted as *word boundary* followed by **star** followed by *word boundary*.

**star**, Jeffrey E. F. Friedl's preferred term for the **asterisk** *metacharacter* must be *escaped* by preceding it with a `\` backslash when one does not wish to use it as a *metacharacter*.

For the string `*` "space**star**space", the above regular expression fails.
[Regex Tester for .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5C*%5Cb&i=%20*%20) tests the above regular expression.

[Here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5C*%5Cb&i=%20*%20&o=i) is the same example as above, but with the *ignore case* option selected.

The following tweak attempts also fail:
`\b[\*]\b`  [character class for **star**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5B%5C*%5D%5Cb&i=%20*%20&o=i)
`\b(\*)\b`  [constraining parentheses](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%5C*%29%5Cb&i=%20*%20&o=i)

other combinations that were tried also failed.

Searching with Google, including SO and MSDN, has been unsuccessful.

in `a`, `\ba\b` the `a` is [found](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cba%5Cb&i=%20a%20&o=i);
in `*`, `\b\*\b` fails to match the **star**

The same results occur in LINQPad 5 and Visual Studio 2015.

Edit   (this fixes the problem for c# .NET)    TIMTWOTDI:

```
\B\*\B
```

See this in the [Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB%5C*%5CB&i=%20*%20) for .NET.

[Wiktor Stribiżew's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) comment was the clue that helped.

On page 133 of the third English edition of [Friedl's](http://regex.info/book.html) book, the author wrote "it would make sense if the word boundaries agree with **\w**, but that is not always the case".

Comment: What is the problem? `\b\*\b` matches a string like `1*2`. `*` is not a word char, there is no word boundary between a space and `*`.

Comment: Do you just want to match any chars that are not preceded/followed with word chars? Use [`@"(?<!\w)\*(?!\w)"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cw%29%5c*%28%3f!%5cw%29&i=+*+&o=i)

Comment: Neither space nor star are words, so space**star**space will never match. Simply put, a word boundary must be between a word and a non-word character.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your first comment helped me see my mistake; `\B\*\B` solves this for me in c# .NET.  My purpose was to determine whether a not T-SQL SELECT statement was a `SELECT * ` for Advantage Database Server; to append `rowID`, one must write  `TABLE.*, rowID `  because the Advantage SQL Engine does not like ` *, rowID ` ~~ thank you Wiktor

Comment: OK, `\B` matches anywhere but at the places matched with a word boundary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew imho my question is not a duplicate because it is specifically about finding an asterisk whereas [Regex word boundary expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468102/regex-word-boundary-expressions) is far more *generic*.

Comment: Well, your question is the result of misunderstanding what word boundaries match. I think it is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide sample strings against which regex is executed, but the [following do match](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5C*%5Cb&i=a*b%0D%0Aa*b*c*d%0D%0Aasdlfkj*fjldsk%0D%0A1*2%0D%0A%20).

```
a*b
a*b*c*d
asdlfkj*fjldsk
1*2
```

It seems you're testing `<space>*<space>` and the reason that doesn't match is because the space is not a word, and neither is the `*`, so there is no word boundary between them, and hence no match.