# Control characters in string sequence

Tags: regex, powershell

String being searched

> "ran into (something-big) issues do something else bla bla, see log
>   file: "

Pattern should find "(something-big) issues" exact substring, if it exists.

How do I allow parens in the regex pattern

This pattern i've tried fails

```
\b\(something-big\) issues\b
```

eg.

```
$str2 = "ran into (something-big) issues do something else bla bla, see log file: ";


if($str2 -match '\b\(something-big\) issues\b' ) {
    Write-Output "we found it";    
}
else{
    Write-Output "nope";
}
```

Comment: this works --- `$str2 -match '\(something-big\) issues'`. i don't know why yours fails, tho. [*blush*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex pattern correctly returns `$false` for your input because of:

```
'\b\(something-big\) issues\b'
# ^ this guy
```

`(` is not a word character, and neither is the space  that precedes it, so the index of `(` [is not actually a word-boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468102/regex-word-boundary-expressions) - remove the first `\b` and it'll work:

```
$str2 -match '\(something-big\) issues\b'
```

---

If you only want to match when a non-word character is present in front of `(something-big)`, use the negated word-character `\W` (notice `W` is upper case):

```
$str2 -match '\W\(something-big\) issues\b'
```

or use a negative lookbehind:

```
$str2 -match '(?<!\w)\(something-big\) issues\b'
```